# How to query a custom content entity with fields added with UI?

Tags: 8, database

In a custom module (assoc), I have a custom Content Entity (Person) with some fields:

```
$fields['lastname'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
$fields['firstname'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
$fields['email'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('email')
$fields['cellphone'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('telephone')
```

I added a field to this entity using the UI:
[image]
I have a query on this entity:

```
  $database = \Drupal::database();
  $query = $database->select('person', 'ap');
  $query->fields('ap', ['id', 'lastname', 'firstname'])
    ->condition('ap.id', 11, '>=')
    ->orderBy('id', 'ASC');
  $results = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
```

I would like to add to the query the field `field_sel_initial_credit`.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try code below:

```
$query->join('person__field_sel_initial_credit','person__field_sel_initial_credit','ap.id=person__field_sel_initial_credit.entity_id');
$qeury->fields('person__field_sel_initial_credit',['field_sel_initial_credit_value']);
```